# Python: How can I call a function that has another function as argument?

Tags: python, function, arguments, call

I have:

```
beta  = 0.95
alpha = 0.3
delta = 0.1

def k_bar(alpha, beta, delta):
    return ((1 / beta - 1 + delta) / alpha) ** (1 / (alpha - 1))
def c_bar(alpha, delta, k_bar):
    return k_bar ** alpha  - delta * k_bar
```

When i call

```
k_bar(alpha, beta, delta)
```

I get "2.63". But
but when i call

```
c_bar(alpha, delta, k_bar)
```

I get "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'function' and 'float'"

However I would like to get the result instead and make the function as argument work in this specific case.

I hope sb. can help me!

Cheers, Tobias

Comment: What do you expect `c_bar(alpha, delta, k_bar)` to return and why?

Comment: `k_bar` is a function - what do you expect the result to be when you multiply a function with a float?

Comment: I expect c_bar to have 1.0733311148204927 since I defined the variables globally and I wanna have the result of the call of k_bar handed in automatically as an argument to c_bar

Comment: looks like you are looking for `c_bar(alpha, delta, k_bar(alpha, beta, delta))` but i can't see how this is advisable in any circumstance..

Comment: So you want `c_bar(alpha, delta, k_bar(alpha, beta, delta))`?

Comment: Out of interest, have you ever done any programming before? And if so, from which language have you come?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that what you actually want to do is have `c_bar` *call* `k_bar`, like this:

```
def k_bar(alpha, beta, delta):
    return ((1 / beta - 1 + delta) / alpha) ** (1 / (alpha - 1))

def c_bar(alpha, beta, delta):
    k = k_bar(alpha, beta, delta)
    return k ** alpha  - delta * k
```

You can call it the same way you call `k_bar`:

```
c = c_bar(alpha, beta, delta)
```

This call will automatically invoke `k_bar` for you.

---

As ACascarino rightly points out, you should note that the `alpha, beta, delta` you define as the function arguments are different to the global variables you define at the top. Inside the function, `alpha` will refer to the function argument.

Comment: I think this is the third time now you've posted an answer seconds before I finish mine! Good work as ever.
The only thing I'll add  for the question asker is that there is a distinction between _global variables_ and _local variables_; just because you've said that a function takes parameters called `alpha`, `beta`, and `delta`, doesn't mean that it's going to use the global variables with the same name!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. In your case, how would I call the function to see the result in the way like for k_bar: Edit: i.e. k_bar(alpha, beta, delta) Edit 2: Maybe I use "call" incorrectly...I just wanna have a easy command to see the results of c_bar only providing alpha, beta, delta Edit 3: Ah Sorry, It works! My Bad and thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

I think you have some problem on what is a function.

According your comments, you want to do:

```
 k_bar = ((1 / beta - 1 + delta) / alpha) ** (1 / (alpha - 1))
```

which is not a function.

[A short trick for beginner, never use the same variable name for two different things (like tour alpha, k_bar).  I make you much more difficult to find the error: you expect in one place, but it is in an other place].

If you send a function as argument, fine, but than it remain a function, so it needs the parameters:

```
def c_bar(alpha, delta, k_bar):
    return k_bar(alpha, beta, delta) ** alpha  - delta * k_bar(alpha, beta, delta)
```

Note: delta in not defined inside c_bar.

Answer (score 1):

Just call:

`c_bar(alpha, delta, k_bar(alpha, beta, delta))`

This way you pass the returned value of `k_bar` to `c_bar`